# Get span title using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have this span and I want to get the title

```
<span title="Something"></span>
```

How to get that with beautifulsoup?

```
res = soup.find('span')
print res //Was trying to add res.title but result is 'None'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to access it like this:

`res = soup.find('span')['title']`

[Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20attributes%20of%20Tags)

Edit: I shoudl clarify, res would then be the value of the title attribute.  If you want the element to use later, change my code to:

```
res = soup.find('span')
title = res['title']
```

Then you could keep using `res` (if needed).

Also, `.find` is going to return a single element.  You'll want to make sure it is the span you want, since the HTML could have more than one span.

Comment: This span is the first span, so i ok with that.. Thanks for your your help again...

Comment: Another one question... i need one text that is between </span> and <a href etc...> and is inside in one <div> with other contents how I can get it? So ...<div class="cs1">....</span>100<a href....>...</div>

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'm not sure.  You may want to start another question with that one.  I'm thinking that there is a way with BeutifulSoup to get you the inner text of an element, without tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is what the documentation has:

```
soup.findAll(['title', 'p'])
# [<title>Page title</title>, 
#  <p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>, 
#  <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>]

soup.findAll({'title' : True, 'p' : True})
# [<title>Page title</title>, 
#  <p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>, 
#  <p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.</p>]
```

You could also use a Regex.